# Redis Subscriber Hangs

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I'm doing a Redis pub/sub proof of concept using Spring Data Redis and Kotlin Coroutines. The code is pretty straightforward as shown below, but the subscriber doesn't seem to get any messages.

```
package com.example.redis

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import org.springframework.boot.WebApplicationType
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.ReactiveRedisTemplate
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializationContext
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer

@SpringBootApplication
class RedisPubSubApplication {
    @Bean
    fun reactiveRedisTemplate(
        reactiveRedisConnectionFactory: ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory,
        objectMapper: ObjectMapper
    ): ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, Any> {
        val stringRedisSerializer = StringRedisSerializer()
        val jacksonSerializer = GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper)
        val serializationContext =
            RedisSerializationContext.newSerializationContext<String, Any>()
                .key(stringRedisSerializer)
                .value(jacksonSerializer)
                .hashKey(stringRedisSerializer)
                .hashValue(jacksonSerializer)
                .build()
        return ReactiveRedisTemplate(reactiveRedisConnectionFactory, serializationContext)
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<RedisPubSubApplication>(*args) {
        webApplicationType = WebApplicationType.NONE
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.example.redis

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.map
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.*
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository

@Repository
class UuidRepository(
    private val redisTemplate: ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, Any>,
    private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper
) {
    private val reactiveValueOps = redisTemplate.opsForValue()
    suspend fun save(uuid: Uuid): Boolean = reactiveValueOps.setAndAwait(uuid.userId, uuid)

    suspend fun findById(userId: String): Uuid? = reactiveValueOps.getAndAwait(userId)?.let { toUuid(it) }

    suspend fun publish(uuid: Uuid): Long = redisTemplate.sendAndAwait(UUID_CHANNEL, uuid)

    suspend fun subscribe(): Flow<Uuid> =
        redisTemplate.listenToChannelAsFlow(UUID_CHANNEL)
            .map { toUuid(it.message) }

    private fun toUuid(data: Any): Uuid = objectMapper.convertValue(data, Uuid::class.java)

    companion object {
        private const val UUID_CHANNEL = "UUID_CHANNEL"
    }
}
```

---

```
data class Uuid(
    val userId: String,
    val uuid: String
)
```

---

```
package com.example.redis

import com.asarkar.spring.test.redis.AutoConfigureEmbeddedRedis
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.firstOrNull
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlinx.coroutines.yield
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureEmbeddedRedis
class RedisPubSubApplicationTest(@Autowired private val repo: UuidRepository) {
    private val log: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedisPubSubApplicationTest::class.java)

    @Test
    fun testSetGet() {
        val uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        runBlocking {
            assertThat(repo.save(Uuid(id, uuid))).isTrue
            val uuid1 = repo.findById(id)
            assertThat(uuid1).isNotNull
            assertThat(uuid1!!.userId).isEqualTo(id)
            assertThat(uuid1.uuid).isEqualTo(uuid)
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun testPubSub() {
        val uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val latch = CountDownLatch(1)
        var uuid1: Uuid? = null
        runBlocking {
            launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                log.info("Going to subscribe")
                uuid1 = repo.subscribe()
                    .firstOrNull()
                latch.countDown()
            }
            yield()
            log.info("Going to publish")
            repo.publish(Uuid(id, uuid))
            assertThat(latch.await(2L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isTrue
            assertThat(uuid1).isNotNull
            assertThat(uuid1!!.userId).isEqualTo(id)
            assertThat(uuid1!!.uuid).isEqualTo(uuid)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.20"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.20"
}

group = "com.example.redis"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json")
//  implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    runtimeOnly("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactive")
//  implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
//  testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
    testImplementation("com.asarkar.spring:embedded-redis-spring:latest.release")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

The `testPubSub` fails because the lock times out. I verified from Redis CLI that publish works.

Comment: @todd I came across your [blog post](https://todd.ginsberg.com/post/springboot-reactive-kotlin-coroutines) on this topic, would you have any idea what's wrong here?